# Set access-modifier to a C++ #define CONSTANT_NAME constant_value

Tags: c++, access-modifiers

I've a library (`MyLib.h` and `MyLib.cpp`) which offers routines to some classes (i.e. `ClassX`, `ClassY`, etc.).
In `MyLib.h` I have defined two constants by using the `#define` preprocessor directive:

```
#define LOCAL_STR "this string can not be shared among classes that don't #include "MyLib.h""

#define TOSHARE_STR "this string can be shared among classes that #include "MyLib.h""
```

Both strings values suggest where I would like to use each string. In my mind, the 1st one must be used only in `MyLib.cpp` code, while the 2nd one inside `ClassX`, `ClassY`, etc. code.

Does C++ provide a way to define the desired visibility for these two constants? Currently they are visible everywhere...

Comment: classes don't #include things, translation units do. #defines are not constants, they are textual substitution rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way of making sure that your LOCAL_STR #define is only used in MyLib.cpp is to put it there, rather than in MyLib.h

Answer (score 2):

You're using the preprocessor features this way by making them `#define`d constants. Using this mechanism, they are visible in whichever module includes the definition.

What you really want to do is declare a constant string (`std::string` or `const char*`) in the relevant classes, and use the visibility controls `public`, `protected` and `private` to control how they are accessed.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  no.

String literals are formally constant arrays of static storage duration.     There is no means of controlling where they are used, as long as the compiler has visibility of their definition.    And their address (or the address of any of their element) can be passed to any function as an argument.

Preprocessor macros are independent of scope, but exist in each compilation unit from the point of their `#define` to the end of the compilation unit or a corresponding `#undef`  (whichever comes first).

This means that any compilation unit that `#include`s your header will have visibility of both macros, and both string literals.

It is often considered poor style to use macros in C++ (except for include guards) since there are alternative mechanisms.   If you want to control access to strings, make them a named member of your class, with appropriate access control.   Instead of using macros and string literals declared in header files.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how a preprocessor works, anyway, you could compile each source separetely and feed the compiler with macros instead of compiling every file at once, so, you could have something like:

hello.h

```
#ifdef PREPROCESSING
  #define STR "this is only seen in hello.c"
#endif
```

hello.c

```
#include "hello.h"
/* STR == "this is ...." */
```

This could be compiled as an object with the `-c` flag and, if you pass "PREPROCESSING" as macro (with the -D option), then the ifdef in the hello.h will pass, defining your string

```
gcc -c -DPREPOROCESSING hello.c -o hello.o
```

After this, you can link several .o files together, each of those will have defined it's own macros without sharing them.

If you need some shared ones you can either use yet another .h file or define them out the ifdef block